# Async dispatch inside a function - compiler getting too aggressive?

Tags: swift, macos, asynchronous

Ran across an interesting one today. Loading up a window controller that I pop up for some task-specific UI stuff. I was just working on the actual window layout dynamics, and wanted to suppress the loading of a configured view controller into one of the views - Just slapped a "return" in the load-up function, thinking that it would exit the function before the async call to load the VC.

```
func setContainer( container:ListContainer ){
    self.container = container
    return
        
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // return
        let vs = ListsViewController()
        vs.setLists(lists: self.container.itemLists)
        vs.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.listsBox.frame.width, height: self.listsBox.frame.height)
        self.listsBox.subviews.removeAll()
        self.listsBox.addSubview(vs.view)
    }
}
```

Interestingly, with that first return in there, the stuff inside the async call still executed, like the compiler is saying "that return doesn't apply to the async call because I said so."

The (currently commented out) return inside the async block does exactly the right thing, but I thought it odd that the async block would still run, with appearing after the return. Am I nuts?

macOS Catalina,
macOS application,
Xcode 12.0.1,
Swift 5 (presumably)

Comment: What if you put a semicolon after `return`?

Comment: Is the issue happening in debug or release builds?

Comment: This issue is addressed in https://mateuszkarwat.com/post/return-keyword/

You should see an XCode warning: "Expression following ‘return’ is treated as an argument of a ‘return’."

Comment: @AlexanderLi, I think Xcode was having a bit of a moment; it didn't start showing that warning until I exited out (for lunch break) and came back in after lunch. But yeah, totally expected, and I just didn't think it through in the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. Your function returns `Void`,  a type that has a single value `()`. DispatchQueue.main.async also returns Void. With your return you are returning the result of DispatchQueue.main.async (which is again `()`). As matt suggested in the comments add a `;` after return.

Comment: This only applies if the `return` and the `Dispatch...` are on the same line. Otherwise it is a parser bug if the compiler really returns the `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Not so. The compiler should warn (in recent versions of Swift), but having `return` and the thing being returned on separate lines is legal and always has been.

Comment: Exactly. In some other languages (Kotlin comes to mind) the value must be on the same line as the return statement, but not so in Swift.

Comment: HAH! omg. one semicolon would fix that. Yep, brain fade. Thanks, all.

Comment: And yes, @DávidPásztor, that *should* be how it works, and I agree that probably *should* kick a warning. I actually really do prefer semi-colons for their exacting clarity.